# Function with several arguments

Tags: math-mode, matrices

I want to .tex the attached. I tried using `\begin{pmatrix}.....\end{pmatrix}`, but didn't give the required. Any help is much appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Aren't `1` and `2` indices for *φ*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i think this is what you're looking for.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\[
 2\phi_1 \biggl(
 \begin{matrix}
  az, a/z \\ ab
 \end{matrix}
 \biggm |
 q, \frac{bt}{a}
 \biggr)
\]

\end{document}
```

[image: output of example code]

`pmatrix` won't work because of the vertical rule in the middle.

Comment: i'm not sure about the size/position of the numerals accompanying the `\phi`.  if you can tell me what they're supposed to look like, i'll fix this.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an implementation that changes size in text style and display style:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools,xparse}

\NewDocumentCommand{\hyper}{mommmm}{%
  \IfValueTF{#2}{\prescript{}{#2}{#1}^{}_{#3}}{#2^{}_{#3}}%
  \innerhyper{{#4}{#5}{#6}}
}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\innerhyper}[1]{\mathpalette\inner@hyper{#1}}
\newcommand{\inner@hyper}[2]{\inner@@hyper{#1}#2}
\newcommand{\inner@@hyper}[4]{%
  \ifx#1\displaystyle\!\left(\else\bigl(\fi
  \begin{\ifx#1\displaystyle\else small\fi matrix}
  #2 \\ #3
  \end{\ifx#1\displaystyle\else small\fi matrix}
  \ifx#1\displaystyle\;\middle|\;\else\bigm|\fi
  #4
  \ifx#1\displaystyle\right)\else\bigr)\fi
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

$\hyper{\phi}[2]{1}{az,a/z}{ab}{q,\frac{bt}{a}}$
\[
\hyper{\phi}[2]{1}{az,a/z}{ab}{q,\frac{bt}{a}}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
  2$\phi_{1}$$\left(
           \begin{array}{ll|ll}
               az,  & a/z &    & bt\\
                    &     & q, & -\\
                    & ab  &    & a \\
            \end{array}
           \right)$
\end{document}
```

[image]